# Docker best practice to access host's services

Tags: postgresql, docker

What is best practice to access the host's services within a docker container?

I'd like to access `PostgreSQL` running on the host within my application which runs in a docker container.

The easiest approach I've found is to use `docker container run --net="host"` which, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/7713760) answer, behaves as follows:

> Such a container will share the network stack with the docker host and from the container point of view, localhost (or 127.0.0.1) will refer to the docker host.
>
> Be aware that any port opened in your docker container would be opened on the docker host. And this without requiring the -p or -P docker run option.

Which does not seem to be best practice since the containers should be isolated from the host.

Other approaches I've found are `awk`ing the hosts IP. May this be the way to go?

Comment: To be honest The Best practice is dockerize you `Postgres`

Comment: @BukharovSergey I know but at this time this is not possible for several reasons and not what I asked.

Comment: @BukharovSergey to be honest, it is not. At least RedHat recommends using stand-alone DB for OpenShift.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Could you provide the article? I would like to understand why they do it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option in this case to treat the host as a remote machine. That way the container will be portable and would not have a strict dependency on network locations when connecting to the database.

In addition to what is mentioned on the drawbacks of using `--network=host`, this option will tightly couple the container to the host by assuming that the database is found on `localhost`.

The way to treat the machine as a remote one, is to use standard network constructs such as IP and DNS. Define a new DNS entry for the container that will point to the host where the DB is found using the
`--add-host` option to docker run.

```
docker run --add-host db-static:<ip-address-of-host> ...
```

Then inside the container you connect to the database via `db-static`

Comment: Wish I could give more upvotes, pretty well explained!

Comment: I still don't understand completely. what exact ip should be put as the `<ip-address-of-host>`? does `db-static:127.0.0.1` work?